# Ionic 2 ngFor update data in view

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic2, ngfor

In my project **'Infinite scroll calendar'** I use ngFor to interate over object using 'pipe' mapToIterable.

Unfortunately, I notice when I add new properties to object on view variable is updated but ngFor not updating the list.
The thing is that when I enter the view it fills fine but when I scroll down it successfully retrieves data from API but not update the list in ngFor..

I tried workaround problem by placing code in `zone.run()` without success.

```
#ionic info

Your system information:

Cordova CLI: 6.4.0 
Ionic Framework Version: 2.0.0-rc.3
Ionic CLI Version: 2.1.18
Ionic App Lib Version: 2.1.9
Ionic App Scripts Version: 0.0.45
ios-deploy version: Not installed
ios-sim version: Not installed
OS: Linux 4.4
Node Version: v6.5.0
Xcode version: Not installed
```

Time for some code:

```js
// mapToIterable.pipe.ts
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({name: 'mapToIterable'})
export class MapToIterablePipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(value): any {
    let keys = [];
    for (let key in value) {
      keys.push({ key: key, value: value[key]});
    }
    return keys;
  }
}
```

.

```
// index.ts
export class Appointments {
  appointments = {};
  current_date = new Date();
  top_date: any = new Date(+new Date - 12096e5);  // 14 days past
  bottom_date: any = new Date(+new Date + 12096e5);  // 14 day future
  range = {
    start_date: this.top_date,
    end_date: this.bottom_date
  }

  generateDays = function (start, end) {
    while(start < end) {
      start.setDate(start.getDate() + 1);
      this.appointments[start.toISOString().slice(0, 10)] = [];
    }
  };

  fillDays = function () {
    this.appointmentService.all(this.range).map(res => res.json()).subscribe(
      data => {
        for (var appointment in data) {
          this.appointments[appointment] = data[appointment];
        }
      },
      err => {
        console.log(JSON.parse(err._body));
      }
    );
  };

  constructor(
    public navCtrl: Nav,
    public appointmentService: AppointmentService,
  ) {
    var temp_date: any = new Date(this.top_date);
    this.generateDays(temp_date, this.bottom_date);
    this.fillDays();
  }

  moreFuture(infiniteScroll) {
    setTimeout(() => {
      var temp_date: any = new Date(this.bottom_date);
      this.bottom_date = new Date(+temp_date + 12096e5); // add 14 days
      this.range.start_date = temp_date;
      this.range.end_date = this.bottom_date;
      this.generateDays(temp_date, this.bottom_date);
      this.fillDays();
      infiniteScroll.complete();
    }, 500);
  };
}
```

.

```
// index.html
 <ion-content padding>
  {{appointments | json}}
  <ion-list class="calendar-list">
    <div *ngFor="let appointment of appointments | mapToIterable" [id]="appointment.key">
      <ion-item class="day past">
        <ion-avatar class="date" item-left>
          <h1>{{appointment.key | date: 'dd'}}</h1>
          <h2>{{appointment.key | date: 'MMM'}}</h2>
        </ion-avatar>
        <div *ngIf="!!appointments[appointment.key].length">
          <ion-avatar class="inline" text-center padding>
            {{appointments[appointment.key][0].patient.first_name[0]}}{{appointments[appointment.key][0].patient.last_name[0]}}
          </ion-avatar>
          <div class="inline">
            <h2 class="username" text-wrap>
              {{appointments[appointment.key][0].patient.first_name}}
              {{appointments[appointment.key][0].patient.last_name}}
            </h2>
            <p>
              <ion-icon name="clock-gray"></ion-icon>
              {{appointments[appointment.key][0].time_start | date: 'HH:mm'}}
              -
              {{appointments[appointment.key][0].time_end | date: 'HH:mm'}}
            </p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </ion-item>
    </div>
    <ion-infinite-scroll (ionInfinite)="moreFuture($event)">
      <ion-infinite-scroll-content></ion-infinite-scroll-content>
    </ion-infinite-scroll>
  </ion-list>
</ion-content>
```

The reason is that I'm using an object rather than an array?

I will be grateful for every answer :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because you are using a 'pure pipe' which executes when the value or reference it is applied to changes. 
It does not detect object property changes.In your case, the `mapToIterable` pipe is not aware of the changes occuring to properties of your object [Check here](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/pipes.html#!#Pure%20and%20Impure%20Pipes)

Try

```
@Pipe({name: 'mapToIterable',pure:false})
```

Comment: Thank you :)
I've seen it before but I did not think that it is so crucial :/
I tried to modify the code to use Observable and the solution was so simple..

Comment: I have been through the same thing. found it the hard way :)